# How to distinguish between different "types" of System.UnauthorizedAccessException in UWP application?

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2015, uwp

This code snippet tries to read a file outside the location allowed for UWP apps:

```
StorageFile sf2 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Path.Combine("C:\\Temp", "spam.dat"));
```

throws System.UnauthorizedAccessException which is intercepted by a Visual Studio 2015 debugger and shown in a nice popup:

[image: WinRT exception dialog]

The entire text is below:

An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: Cannot access the specified file or folder (C:\Temp\spam.dat). The item is not in a location that the application has access to (including application data folders, folders that are accessible via capabilities, and persisted items in the StorageApplicationPermissions lists). Verify that the file is not marked with system or hidden file attributes.

An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Now another code snippet (this code tries to read a file which is already opened for writing):

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path);
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("spam.dat", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
Stream fs = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
StorageFile sf2 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "spam.dat"));
await sf2.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
```

The exception screen in the debugger looks completely different:

[image: Normal exception dialog]

Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I don't understand how debugger looks different for these exceptions. In my code, I need to understand the reason of getting UnauthorizedAccessException - if it was because file is locked for reading as it's occupied by another writer (and I can try again a bit later) or due to another reason, like it's outside of LocalFolder (and it's not worth retrying). I'm actually developing a library which will be used by developers of UWP apps so I don't know which file/filepath I will be given and can make no assumptions for permissions, directory structure, etc. I just get the path on input and, if anything happens, can only use exception handling to understand the reasons.

So, Visual Studio debugger somehow sees the difference but I don't see how I can do this programmatically. InnerException is null in both cases, HResult is the same either (0x80070005).

Comment: How exactly is your library going to be used by other developers? What is it going to be doing? It might be that the best thing for you to do is to not handle the exception so that consumers of your code can decide how they want to handle the situation.

Comment: The library is expected to deal with situation when multiple threads or even app instances can read and write from/into the same shared files simultaneously. The behavior is already set, I cannot change it. The library  already behaves this way for other .NET platforms, I'm just making a UWP port.

Comment: And I'm curious why Visual Studio debugger displays these exceptions so differently.. What's so different between them?

Answer (score 1):

If you're porting a .NET library to UWP, presumably it has no dependencies on `StorageFile` at all (either in implementation or public interface) so I would continue to use .NET types, which have distinct errors (Unauthorized Access vs. IO):

```
try
{
  var f = File.OpenRead(@"d:\temp\foo.txt");
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

try
{
  var localPath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
  var filename = Path.Combine(localPath, "foo.txt");
  var f1 = File.OpenWrite(filename);
  var f2 = File.OpenRead(filename);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

If I run your sample code, I don't get any exceptions for the write / read example using `StorageFile` (although I am running Insider Builds of the Windows 10 Creator's Update). I can get an exception if I try to open the same file twice for writing, but then it's **also** projected as an `IOException`:

```
try
{
  var f = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"d:\temp\foo.txt");
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

try
{
  var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
  var f1 = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("foo.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
  var f2 = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("foo.txt");
  var s1 = await f1.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite, StorageOpenOptions.AllowOnlyReaders);
  var s2 = await f2.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite, StorageOpenOptions.AllowOnlyReaders);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. Despite it doesn't answer my question directly, it shows that file access conflict can result not only in UnauthorizedAccessException but also in IOException. The original non-UWP lib indeed handled IOException in this case and while working on migration, I found that this condition does not occur (in my case UnauthorizedAccessException occurred instead). But your case shows IOException again. Seems both my occur under different circumstances.

Comment: I copied your sample code directly and did not get any errors due to sharing violations. It might be something that depends on the specific build of Windows you're running though (I think we might have relaxed the rules recently). Can you try checking the `HResult` property to see if it's different?

Comment: From the original post: InnerException is null in both cases, HResult is the same either (0x80070005).

Comment: I also tried with normal .NET app on the same machine: `FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("log.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate); FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("log.txt", FileMode.Open);` Getting IOException (not UnauthorizedAccessException) `The process cannot access the file '...\log.txt' because it is being used by another process.` UnauthorizedAccessException only happens with UWP for me..

Comment: What build of Windows do you have?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro. Version 10.0.14393 Build 14393.

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

For the second one you are working with the IO stream without disposing the previous stream you are trying to create another stream on the same file. Thus it is preventing you saying unauthorized Access. I have introduced flush the stream and dispose the stream then the code is working for me. Below is the modified code:

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path);
        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("spam.dat", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        Stream fs = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Dispose();
        StorageFile sf2 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "spam.dat"));
        var x = await sf2.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
```

Comment: Your did not understand the whole point. My code is specially crafted to produce this exception. I'm talking about exception handling and to demonstrate it, I need to make this exception to occur.

Comment: ohh sorry yes you already mentioned that. It was my bad. I thought you are getting such exception in the second type of code too..